# SSRS Matrix Variance Column - Report Running Slowly

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

I am creating an SSRS Report based on a Stored Procedure; the procedure calls in the last six months of data based on the month the user enters into a parameter (ex. 201604).  Currently I have this data going into a matrix, and along with those six months the report needs to have a variance column for the latest vs. directly prior month (ex. 201604 vs. 201603)

Right now I have a formula that works using a column that I created within the stored procedure to designate whether the month a row is in is CURRENT, PRIOR, or NONE if it is not being used in the calculation.

```
   =SUM(IIF(Fields!VarHelper.Value = "CURRENT",1,0) * Fields!stock_value.Value
   -
   IIF(Fields!VarHelper.Value = "PRIOR",1,0) * Fields!stock_value.Value)
```

I am using this formula in three areas/cells on the report, and for some reason it is causing the report to run very slowly (around 45 seconds to run).  Without these variance formulas in the report it runs almost instantaneously.

Would someone be able to either a).suggest a better method of calculating the variance between the latest two months in a matrix, or b).be able to at least shed some light on why this may be impacting report performance?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to report the calculations on the query.
Two ways possible : if you made a sql query : make it in the select.
Or, add calculted field in the dataset.
And make sum on these fields.
May be you will win time : because the database server will make the job instead of the report server.